# ControlGroup nested objects

Tags: angular

I'm building a form with ControlGroup. In this form I want to show data that is nested in the database. The JSON of the object looks like this:

```
{duration: 
          {
           time1: 12, 
           time2: 13, 
           price: 100
           }
}

requestForm: ControlGroup;
requestForm.form.group({duration: object.duration});
```

Now in the html I want to bind this key to an input field. This is how I'm trying to do this:

```
<input *ngIf="editable" [ngFormControl]="requestForm.controls['duration.time1']" required="required" value="" type="text">
```

However I get an error telling me it can't find the control ''. I also tried to `duration/time1` instead of `duration.time1`. How am I supposed to do this?